# getting a double array of letters

Tags: c

i am trying to get a matrix made of chars **i am allowed only scanf or getchar** the first line i get are junk chars, and only after i get chars from the first one entered
(printing is just to check, i need to save array),
(MAX and size differ because im not allowed to use malloc, so size is from input):

```
void get_start(char forest[][MAX], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char c;
    printf("Enter first generation: ");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';j++){
            forest[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                printf("%c", forest[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: You must control the inner loop with `j < MAX-1` (-1 is for reserving room for the null character), not `j < size`. Also you must terminate the character sequence with null character after exiting that loop: `forest[i][j] = '\0';`. `c` must be defined as `int`.

Comment: do you read any input in before this function is called? looks like you have a stray `\n` in the input buffer

Comment: I do not need the matrix to be a string, or collection of strings. just a square of letters size*size (size is smaller then MAX). before this function i get a number using: int get_num()
{
    int num;
    if(!scanf("%d",&num)){
        printf("Input error");
        exit(1);
    }
    return num;
} but i have c!='\n' when i get the chars, so why do i get junk?

Comment: and can i solve this without fflush(stdin): ? my teacher did not teach this function, so i am not allowed to use it. though it solves the problem.